# Is there high precision (millisecond) CLI stop watch in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, stopwatch

Is there high precision (millisecond) CLI stop watch in Ubuntu?

Comment: `sudo aptitude install stopwatch`

Comment: I would use it to measure the interval between two signals from RS232 devices.  I know how to write C program, but I'd like to know if there is already the utility.

Comment: @Josh: Have you tried using that in a Command Line User Environment (CLUE, as in "get a clue" :P) or Command Line Interface (the CLI requested here).

Comment: @Roger: Yes I did. Considering I have almost every known package repository added it dutifully informed me there were several choices to pick from. Alas I didn't write them down and suffered a fatal system crash a short while later.

Comment: @Josh: Then it would be helpful to say where you got stopwatch, as my current repositories (which include the defaults) only have a version with just a GUI executable.

Comment: @Roger: As mentioned I suffered a fatal system crash. Those things happen at the worst of times...

Comment: @Josh: `apt-cache show stopwatch` will list the latest version from each repository in which it's available.  Or just repeat the steps you did above and write down the choices it dutifully informs you of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to program it in C, then you want to be looking at the gettimeofday(2) function. This returns a structure which contains a time_t (accurate to the nearest second), and a tv_usec (accurate to the nearest microsecond). By doing two of these, and appropriate math, you can get the interval. Note that even though the systemcall returns microseconds, you can't get an interval that small. The actual resolution can be seen in /proc/timer_list.

Of course, a programing question would be better on stackoverflow.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question?  He doesn't want to write his own program in C.

Comment: According to the OP's comment, that is one of the options he is considering to solve the problem.